# PHP: Compare with zero

Tags: php, comparison

```
<?php
$value = 0;
switch ($value) {
    case $value < 3:
        $output = 'smaller than 3';
        break;
    case $value >= 3 && $value <= 4:
        $output = 'between 3 and 4 (inclusively)';
        break;
    case $value >= 5 && $value <= 6:
        $output = 'between 5 and 6 (inclusively)';
        break;
    case $value >= 6 && $value <= 7:
        $output = 'between 6 and 7 (inclusively)';
        break;
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Why does this output `between 3 and 4 (inclusively)` instead of `smaller than 3`?

..................................................................................

Comment: You might want to _start accepting_ some answers from your previous questions.

Comment: You are misusing `case` syntax and the result doesn't do what you think it does. You are supposed to use only literal values for `case`, not conditions.

Comment: `switch` compares the evaluated value of the `case` expressions with the evaluated value of the `switch` expression. So it actually does `$value == ($value < 3)`, `$value == ($value >= 3 && $value <= 4)`, etc.

Comment: @vlzvl: There are not so much answers to accept. ;-)

Comment: @Jon: It should also work with conditions, shouldn't it?

Comment: @a1277399: No, why should it?

Comment: @Jon: Because of what Gumbo said. What about `switch (true)`?

Comment: @a1277399: I don't see the connection between what Gumbo said and why PHP should offer this or any other feature. `switch(true)` is called a reversed switch (you can see this in the question this is a duplicate of), and it's a way to pull off exactly what you tried to do here. A counter-intuitive, advanced-users-only way. You are saving some keystrokes compared to `if/else`, and the price you pay is that the set of developers that can immediately understand it is dramatically reduced.

Comment: @Jon: Maybe we misunderstand each other. With the use of `switch(true)`, you can use conditions as well as literals for `case`, can't you?

Comment: @a1277399: It's meaningless to use literals with the reversed switch (just as it is meaningless to use conditions with the standard version). Anything you use will be compared to `true`, so you might  as well just test it inside an `if`. Because that's exactly what the reverse does: it allows you to write an `if` that looks like a `switch`. Just write an `if` in the first place.

Comment: @a1277399, you're right, apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switch()` should be `true` but your `$value` is `0`. Zero is considered as `false`. For condition you can simply use `if` then `elseif`. Try this..

```
$value = 0;
if($value < 3){
    $output = 'smaller than 3';
}elseif($value >= 3 && $value <= 4){
    $output = 'between 3 and 4 (inclusively)';
}elseif($value >= 5 && $value <= 6){
    $output = 'between 5 and 6 (inclusively)';
}elseif($value >= 6 && $value <= 7){
    $output = 'between 6 and 7 (inclusively)';
}
echo $output;
```

**Output:**
`smaller than 3`